# Web Audio API how to name sounds

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

So at the moment two sounds are loaded in a buffer which are then connected to two sources. How can I name the two sounds in the BufferLoader as "kick" and "hihat" then play them using kick.start(0). I know it must be easy but I can't find anything through searching.

```
window.onload = init;
var context = new AudioContext();
var bufferLoader;

function init() {

  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
    context,
    [
      'kick.wav',
      'hihat.wav',
    ],
    finishedLoading
    );

  bufferLoader.load();
}

function finishedLoading(bufferList) {

  var source1 = context.createBufferSource();
  var source2 = context.createBufferSource();
  source1.buffer = bufferList[0];
  source2.buffer = bufferList[1];

  source1.connect(context.destination);
  source2.connect(context.destination);
  source1.start(0);
  source2.start(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the abstraction I wrote for myself if you like:

```
function audioFileLoader(fileDirectory) {
    var soundObj = {};
    soundObj.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;

    var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getSound.open("GET", soundObj.fileDirectory, true);
    getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    getSound.onload = function() {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
            soundObj.soundToPlay = buffer;

        });
    }

    getSound.send();


    soundObj.play = function() {
        var playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        playSound.buffer = soundObj.soundToPlay;
        playSound.connect(audioContext.destination)
        playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime)
    }

    return soundObj;

};

var snare = audioFileLoader("snare.mp3");


snare.play()
```